# Need a sample serenityBDD project

Tags: serenity-bdd

I am very new to serenity BDD, I don't know how to create tests in serenity.
anyone, please help me, I want one sample serenityBDD project that would launch the browser and run the tests. If anyone has sample project please share it.

Comment: How about this? https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-test-projects

Comment: Thank you for your response, i hope it will be useful to me.

Comment: in above sample projects, some commands are there to execute the project as a gradle, i was trying to execute as a maven build using "clean verify" command. so i was passing the command as a goal.But for gradle how to pass "./gradlew clean build" command??

Answer (score 0):

You can also use maven archetypes as described in this tutorial(first 2 minutes):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-6CcDFn5Ug

In a command window(of course you need to have maven installed first):
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=serenity

You then choose:
- the kind of archetype you want (choice between serenity-cucumber, serenity-jbehave, serenity-screenplay-junit),
- the version of this specific archetype,
- define a GroupId for your package,
- define an ArchetypeID
[-optional version]
[-optional package name]

And that's it, you've got your skeleton serenity project.